# How to tap on ToolbarItem in Xamarin.Forms UITest?

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I have set an **AutomationId** for my `ToolbarItem`:

```
<ToolbarItem  AutomationId="A_Edit"
        Icon="icon_create.png"
        Priority="0"
        Order="Primary"
        Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
```

This is the method I am using in my test:

```
app.Tap(x => x.Marked("A_Edit"));
```

But this doesn't work for toolbar items.

Comment: Have you tried using the REPL tool to see if UITest is detecting the element? One way is to launch the REPL, navigate to a screen that shows the toolbar in your app and then use the "tree" command: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/repl/

Comment: It is working fine by REPL.Thank you so much

Comment: When it works in the REPL tool, did you use the same query, or did you change the query? If `app.Tap(x => x.Marked("A_Edit"));` _only_ works in the REPL tool it may be a bug.